# Convert a String into a set<Character> using a Stream java 8

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

```
private static final String ALPHABET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
SortedSet<Character> set= new TreeSet<Character>();
for (int i = 0; i < ALPHABET.length(); i++) {
    set.add(new Character(ALPHABET.charAt(i)));
 }
```

I would like to convert this for loop in Java 8 way. It could be better if using a stream. Output will be the "set" object with contains the Character.

Comment: `new Character(…)` is obsolete since Java 5. You can simply write `set.add(ALPHABET.charAt(i));`.

Comment: To clarify @Holger's comment: it's obsolete because of [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`String` has a method which will give you a stream of characters. It's actually an `IntStream` so we just need to convert them to `Character`s and then `collect` to a set.

```
"foo".chars()
    .mapToObj(chr -> (char) chr) // autoboxed to Character
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

or use `TreeSet::new` as [others](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54456820/1898563) have [shown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54456866/1898563) if you need the set to be sorted.

Answer (score 7):

```
 IntStream.range(0, ALPHABET.length())
          .mapToObj(ALPHABET::charAt)
          .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));
```

Comment: Guess you meant *length*, not lenght.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is the simplest way, preserving the requirement of using a `TreeSet`. Notice that there's no need to iterate over the input string using *indexes*, you can directly iterate over its characters.

```
SortedSet<Character> set =
    ALPHABET.chars()
            .mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));
```

Comment: You ended up with same solution as Michael [proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54456837/10584605).

Comment: @ETO It doesn't matter. We were both editing our answers after we posted them. Anyway, Stack Overflow isn't supposed to be *fastest* to answer, it's *best* to answer.

Comment: @proposed Mmmm he referenced the suggestion to use a TreeSet, and I explained why it's better to iterate over the alphabet. Each solution has its own contributions, it's ok.